# What does this mean? npm WARN deprecated es5-shim@2.3.0

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am setting up a development environment and I ran into a little issue (i guess).

When I run npm install, it takes all the dependencies specified in the package.js and installs them, as far as I know.

But for some reason whenever I execute that command I get :

> npm WARN deprecated es5-shim@2.3.0: Please update to the latest
>   version; it over rides noncompliant native methods even in modern
>   implementations

Well I have no idea  what this message means, so I hope maybe someone can help.

This is my package.js :

```
{
    "name":"recapday",
    "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/magestican/Recapday-UI.git"
    },
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "devDependencies":{
        "express": "~4.8.5",
        "grunt": "~0.4.5",
        "grunt-angular-templates": "~0.5.7",
        "grunt-browserify": "~1.2.11",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.1",
        "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.7.0",
        "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.8.0",
        "grunt-exec": "~0.4.6",
        "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.11.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: One or more package you have in `devDependencies` depends on package called `es5-shim`, which is this: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim. Hopefully this will clear up something for you

Comment: It means there is a newer version of es5-shim.

Comment: It means there is a newer version of es5-shim.

Answer (score 0):

One of the packages that you listed as your dependency, namely "grunt-contrib-jasmine" has its own dependency on es5-shim version 2.3.0.  Version 2.3.0 is old, and this is a warning that the author of  "grunt-contrib-jasmine" should update to the latest version of es5-shim.

You could overwrite the nested dependencies using shrinkwrap mechanism, explained here:  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap  This will allow you to overwrite the grunt-contrib-jasmine dependencies on es5-shim@2.3.0, and could force the package to use a newer version of your choice.